# Are there dense sets of positive but not full measure?

Tags: real-analysis

This topic came out today during a discussion with a colleague. I realized that a counter-example to his claim could be constructed if there exits a subset $A \subset [0,1]$ such that $0 < \mu(A) < 1$ (where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure), $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$ (with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$), $\textit{and } A \textit{ does not contain an interval}$. However, I am not sure whether such a set exists. So the question is: do such sets exist? If so, is there an explicit construction, if not, how does one prove non-existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Central Limit Theorem, something like this should have the
property that $0<\mu([a,b]\cap A)<b-a$ for all $0\leq a<b\leq 1$. Let
$0.a_1a_2\cdots$ be the binary expansion of $x\in[0,1]$. Let $A$
consist of all $x$ such that for all $n$ sufficiently large,
  $$ -1 < \frac{\frac n2-(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)}{\sqrt{n}}<1. $$
The bounds $-1$ and $1$ could be replaced by any $\alpha<\beta$ in
$\mathbb{R}$.

For another solution see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow $A$ to contain an interval, let
$$A = (\mathbb Q\cap [0,1])\cup [0,1/2].$$
If not,
consider $q_i$ the $i$th rational number in some enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$, and let
$$A=\bigcup^\infty_{i=1} (q_i-4^{-i}, q_i+4^{-i})\cap (\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)$$

Comment: My apologies, I intended to not consider trivial sets which contain intervals

Comment: The second example of Kjos-Hanssen does contain an interval. For an example not containing an interval, simply take $A=([0,1/2]-\mathbb{Q})\cup([1/2,0]\cap \mathbb{Q})$. However, I am guessing that the condition you actually want is that for all $0\leq a<b\leq 1$, we have $0<\mu([a,b]\cap A)<b-a$.

Comment: One may exhibit cantor subsets of $[0,1]$ with any measure between $0$ and $1$ inclusive, by an explicit construction where at stage $n$ one removes the central part of proportion $a_n$, for a suitable sequence. 

Take the union of such a set with $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: Constructing a measurable subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ such that $0 < \mu(A\cap [a,b]) < b-a$ for any $0\le a < b\le 1$ is an old and well-known elementary exercise in Measure Theory; see Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.